# Limit size of AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a decentralized application (I don't control the servers, only the client), and want to add some sanity checks and preventative measures to stop bad people from doing malicious things. This involves (among many, many other things), preventing DoS attempts on the client by the use of arbitrary payload data being sent from the servers.

How can the client limit the maximum size of data received from a server over jQuery via AJAX? If I'm expecting to fetch a few bytes of JSON, and am instead greeted by a 30MB video file when I make the AJAX request, how can I stop the request and throw an error after I've received the first 16 KB?

Comment: You can't control what server sends. Question doesn't really make any sense

Comment: Only thing you could do is try a HEAD request and check content length header before making GET

Comment: *"How can the client limit the maximum size"* They can't, unless you, as the API developer, add a way to handle that. So, if you have control over the API, you can implement some limits via something like sending a `max_results` or `max_response_size` key in the payload, but arbitrarily, that's not a thing that I've ever seen.

Comment: @charlietfl I know I can't control it, but would just like to "abort" the request if the response is too big. I'm using IPFS for looking up hashes, so don't think HEAD will work

Comment: Many APIs for doing bulk requests have a parameter that specifies how many results to return.

Comment: @TimLewis I'm using IPFS, and I don't control the IPFS peers the client connects to. I can't control the length of content which is stored, so need to enforce everything client-side. Since there is no central server, all the protocol-level stuff needs to be controlled by the client.

Comment: You can use the same mechanism you would use to display a progress bar. If it gets too much, you can calcel the request.

Comment: @Barmar in the background, the IPFS peer node to which the client connects resolves the hash of the content. Prior to resolution, the client doesn't know the length of the content. I don't control to whom the client connects (it must remain compatible with all IPFS-HTTP gateways). My question is, client-side, how I can "stop" the request if the response becomes too large, prior to downloading the entire thing. This would avoid DOS attempts where the client downloads 100MB of data, only to find it was just garbage and to reject it.

Comment: @TyEverett Like I said, use the progress event. One of the values it receives is the current position in the response. If it gets above your desired limit, abort the XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @Barmar No accurate progress bar can be displayed since the size of the end result is not known. Typically however, the size shouldn't exceed a few KB at most. I just don't know how to enforce this in my unique context of having to use IPFS.
EDIT: Will check into this, thank you.

Comment: @TyEverett i dont think you understand how it works. Please look up avoid DOS attempts, this usually has nothing to do with size. regardless of this, the client can not control global limits. Client request what they have access to.. if they have access the sever will respond. if your controlling the client then just dont give them the option to download what you dont want them to.... and also if for some reason your using a public api then check the size which has been received like Barmar said.

Comment: you imply that clients can randomly trick the server into sending more than you would like, this is simply not possible... the server will only response with what was requested, BOTH the client and the server are fixed. you can request A and receiver A response, it wont respond with anything else, its simply not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Barmar pointed out in the comments, this was a simple case of checking the "onprogress" event of the download and terminating it when it exceeded my desired max size.

Here is the code for any interested parties:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: "your-url",
    success: () => {
        // ...
    },
    xhrFields: {
        onprogress: function(progress) {
          if (progress.loaded > config.MAX_HASH_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE) {
            // stop any unreasonably long malicious payload downloads.
            xhr.abort()
          }
        }
      }
})
```